# Cambiar de posición Sí y No al pasar el ratón y que vuelva a la posición original tras moverlo

Tags: javascript

No tengo muy claro cómo lograrlo. ¿Alguien me echa una mano?

```js
var aleatori=1;
 
function si() {
 window.alert("Enhorabona");
}

function no() {
 var confirma = window.confirm("Estàs segur que no vols aprobar?");

 if (confirma == true){
  window.alert("Ens veiem a la recuperació");
 }
 else window.alert("Torna a intentar-ho");

}

//hacer una funcion por la cual si if está activado en tornar a intentar que no se active la funcion

function altraVegada(a) {
 aleatori=parseInt(Math.random() * 5);
 console.log(aleatori);
}

function swap (){
  if(aleatori!=0){ 
  console.log(aleatori);
  console.log(document.getElementById("yes"));
  document.getElementById("no").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("yes").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("again").style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById("again").style.left = "3%";
  document.getElementById("no").style.left = "0.5%";
  document.getElementById("yes").style.left="11.3%";
 }
}
```

```html
</br></br>
¿VOLS APROBAR?</br>
<input type="button" id="yes" value="Sí" onclick="si()" onmouseout="swap2()" onmouseover="swap()" >
<input type="button" id="again" value="Tornau a intentar" onclick= "altraVegada(yes)" >
<input type="button" id="no" value="No" onclick= "no()" >
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: swap2 is not defined`

Comment: Hola @TovarishAlex, como te indica otro usuario en un comentario, falta una función (swap2) para poder ver el problema. Por favor edita la pregunta para añadir un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro al parecer la función faltante `swap2` sería el `restore` donde se trabó

Answer (score 0):

usando unos divs temporales para hacer el swap dentro de un contenedor y con algo de css para que no haya saltos sale algo divertido:

```js
var elAgain = document.getElementById("again");
var elSi = document.getElementById("si");
var elNo = document.getElementById("no");
var elContenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
var siTemp = document.createElement("div");
var noTemp = document.createElement("div");

function si() {
  console.log("si")
}

function no() {
  console.log("no")
}

function altraVegada(loQue) {
  console.log("va de nuevo", loQue)
}

function swap() {
  elContenedor.replaceChild(siTemp, elSi);
  elContenedor.replaceChild(noTemp, elNo);
  elContenedor.replaceChild(elNo, siTemp);
  elContenedor.replaceChild(elSi, noTemp);
}

function restore() {
  elContenedor.appendChild(elSi);
  elContenedor.appendChild(elAgain);
  elContenedor.appendChild(elNo);
}
```

```css
#si,
#no {
  width: 40px;
}

input[type=button] {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
</br>
</br>
¿VOLS APROBAR?</br>
<div id=contenedor>
  <input id=si
    type="button" value="Sí"
    onclick="si()" onmouseout="restore()" onmouseenter="swap()"><input id=again
    type="button" value="Tornau a intentar"
    onclick="altraVegada('yes')"><input id=no
    type="button" value="No" onclick="no()" onmouseout="restore()"
    onmouseenter="swap()">
</div>
```

Comment: Acabas de salvarme la vida, muchas gracias!